# How to keep a checkbox checked?

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

How to keep selected checkbox checked after a dynamic search?
After every search, the selected checkbox is unchecked.

Here is my code:
https://github.com/cdjordje/Test1.git

I tried this but it doesn`t work properly:

```js
jQuery(function(){
    if (localStorage.input) {
        var checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.input);
        jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(i) {
            return checks[i];
        });
    }
});

jQuery(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = JSON.stringify(jQuery(':checkbox').map(function() {
        return this.checked;
    }).get());
});
```

Comment: I've never known `localStorage` to work the way you have it, as there are `getItem` and `setItem` functions (among others). See [example usage here](https://rxdb.info/articles/localstorage.html). Also, localStorage seems extreme for the need, because the get/post info of the form should indicate what is/was checked so that those can be set again during reload, unless there is some historical need of what was checked at a later point in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your code in https://github.com/cdjordje/Test1.git according to below instructions.**

Update your index.php file

**Step 1: Add Function outside of document.ready in script of index.php file**

```
var checked_value_array = [];
  function getCheckedValue(THIS){
    var temp = $(THIS).val();

    if($("#lib_id_"+temp).prop('checked') == true){
      checked_value_array.push(temp);
    }else{
      checked_value_array = checked_value_array.filter(function(item) {
      return item !== temp
    });
    
  }
}
```

**Step 2 : Replace load_data function in index.php file with below function**

```
function load_data(page, query = '')
    {
      var temp_arr = JSON.stringify(checked_value_array);
      $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query,temp_arr:temp_arr},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

Update your fetch.php file

**Step 1: Add below code in fetch.php file**

```
$checked_value_array =  json_decode($_POST['temp_arr']);
```

**Step 2 : Replace foreach loop in fetch.php with below foreach loop**

```
foreach($result as $row)
  {
    $checked = '';
    $id = $row['id'];
    if (in_array($id , $checked_value_array)){
      $checked = 'checked';
    }

    $output .= '
    <tr>
      <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
      <td><input class="chkCheckBoxId" type="checkbox" id="lib_id_'.$row['id'].'" onclick="getCheckedValue(this)" name="lib_id[]" value="'. $row['id'] .'"  '.$checked.'></td> 
    </tr>
    ';
  }
```